# I am unable to create this variable

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

How do I create a variable in R, which takes a value
of 0 60% of the time and a value of 1 otherwise?

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  If so, please add the Self Study tag.

Comment: Read about `?rbinom`

Answer (score 2):

R offers a series of functions that produce random samples from common distributions. They are all named "r" followed by an abbreviation of the distribution; "rnorm" - random normal, "rpois" - random poisson, "runif" - random uniform (not run-if), etc. You're looking for "rbinom" - random binomial.

e.g.

```
rbinom(1, 1, 0.4)
```

We use 0.4 instead of 0.6 because the function wants the probability of a 1 as the third argument.

Answer (score 1):

This should probably be on StackOverflow. Anyway,

```
sample(0:1, 1, prob=c(0.6, 0.4))
```